# Bulk File Conversion with Apache Spark

Tags: scala, pdf, apache-spark, etl, tiff

Spark/Scala n00bie here...

I've got a large set of documents whose pages are stored as individual tif images. I need to convert and concatenate the individual tifs' into a single PDF document. i.e  1.tif, 2.tif, 3.tif -> 123.pdf

I've been investigating using Spark to accomplish this. I create the initial RDD like this:

```scala
val inputTifRDD = sc.binaryFile("file:///some/path/to/lots/of/*tif")
```

with inputTifRDD comprised of tuples of the form:

```
(fullFilePath: String, data:org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream )
```

I then apply a custom map function that converts each tif into a pdf and returns a RDD comprised of tuples of the form:

```
(fullFilePath: String, data:com.itextpdf.text.Document)
```

I now want to apply an action to this RDD to concatenate the PDF's into a single PDF. I don't think reducing is possible because the concatenation is not commutative - the order of pages matters.

My question is how do I effect the concatenation of elements in the RDD in the correct order? The filenames contain the page number, so this information can be used. Alternatively - is there another, better/more efficient way to do the conversion/concatentation with Spark?

Comment: It doesn't like a very good use case for Spark. Reduce will put all data on the driver anyway. It would make more sense to simply parallelize job locally.

Comment: @zero323  - thanks for the response. I was worried that infact this might not be a sensible usecase for spark. In terms of exploiting Spark, I wonder if simply using a map to parallelize the tif->pdf part is enough, and then have another non spark job pick up the concatenation task.

Comment: You'll have to experiment with that but my intuition is overall cost of running Spark (synchronization and stuff) can make it less than optimal. Since the job looks quite simple you could be actually better with a single strong machine and parallel `make` or GNU Parallel  :) Especially if you consider that Spark doesn't handle large `binaryFiles` very well.